# Spring Boot 3 SSEEmitter complete triggers cannot forward to error page

Tags: spring-boot

After we upgraded to Spring Boot 3 we always get this error in the log after calling emitter.complete().

It looks like the GET called by the client completes directly when emitter.complete() is called, that makes sense. But that immediately triggers "response has already been committed" error on the server.

How to prevent this error from being logged?

Controller

```
@RestController
public class TradeController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/quotes")
    public ResponseEntity<SseEmitter> getQuotes(
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("X-Accel-Buffering", "no")
                .body(createSseEmitter());
    }

    private SseEmitter createSseEmitter() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(70000L);
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> {
            log.info("Quote SSE emitter is completed for request {}", requestId);
        });
        emitter.onError(throwable -> {
            log.warn("Error on SSE emitter, quote request {}", requestId, throwable);
        });
        emitter.onTimeout(() -> {
            log.warn("Timeout on SSE emitter, quote request {}", requestId);
        });

        return emitter;
    }
```

Code that calls emitter.complete()

```
        try {
            emitter.send(jwtService.createJwtToken(message.toClaimsMap(), 300), TEXT_PLAIN);

            
            // response is final, there will be no more messages
            emitter.complete();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // javadoc of emitter.send() specifically instructs to not call completeWithError; response is already committed
            log.warn("Cannot send response to user: client closed the connection: {}", response, e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // note, when emitter is already completed: emitter.send will throw uncaught IllegalStateException
            log.error("Cannot send response to user: emitter timed out: {}", response, e);
        }
```

```
2024-02-22 16:05:17 2024-02-22 16:05:17,429 [INFO ][http-nio-8080-exec-9] LogFilter.logDetails:66 - [] - [method='GET';uri='/quotes';qs='requestToken=...';path info='null'] in 13 ms
2024-02-22 16:05:17 2024-02-22 16:05:17,432 [ERROR][http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleCommittedResponse:222 - [] - Cannot forward to error page for request [/quotes] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
2024-02-22 16:05:17 org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
2024-02-22 16:05:17     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98)
2024-02-22 16:05:17     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
2024-02-22 16:05:17     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
2024-02-22 16:05:17     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
```

Comment: Can you show how your emitter is being used ? Because with the code you provide it is impossible that the emitter you use to call complete is the same as your /quotes API  answer to the client